# Travelling to Europe before student visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france

I am a US citizen a bit worried about possibly jeopardizing my French student visa by visiting France too much. I went to France in January for two weeks to visit my SO, and he was supposed to come to the US this summer but his tourist visa was denied. I want to visit him in May now, for like 10 days, but I am also applying for a student visa to France to spend the 2019-2020 academic year studying there. Since I cannot apply for the student visa until 3 months within my departure date, I would definitely be back from France before my visa appointment. I am just worried that maybe they will think it's fishy that I already visited France twice this year, or if this is possibly violating some visa law. I really miss my SO and want to see him before September, but I would not want to hurt my chances of getting a student visa in the slightest.

I would very much appreciate any help or insights regarding this issue.
Thank you

Comment: I very much doubt that two short holidays in five months will have any effect at all on your student visa.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not immigration officials and there's no way to tell one way or another. It certainly feels like the answer is "you shouldn't worry" but there is nothing to base this on. Again, just feelings but checking out the country before moving there for a year or more seems natural? I visited Vancouver for a week in February and spent a month in Canada in the summer before filing for my Canadian immigration visa... never occured to me this wouldn't be the natural thing to do. Who would jump in without testing the waters, so to speak?

Comment: Not saying it never happens, but you have a pretty powerful passport. A couple of short-ish holidays over a 5 month period shouldn’t do any harm. You’re not violating any visa laws.

Comment: On a side note, what's an SO?

Comment: @EwigeStudentin SO = Significant Other - boyfriend, girlfriend, husband, wife, partner, etc. Or Stack Overflow 

Comment: Update to this if anyone else sees the question: I was granted the visa of course, and I've also visited Europe before my visa period started for another Schengen country without any issues under the visa waiver (never overstayed the 90/180 rule though).